# prevent protected method from being called when testing public method

Tags: junit

I have been asked a interview question on how to skip a protected method call execution when testing a public method which calls a protected method with in using Junit?

Any help ?

Comment: what do you think? What is your answer?

Comment: I replied we can use Mockito spy to change the method behavior, but he was expecting a answer using pure junit..

Comment: Execute the test on a subclass of the actual class, overriding the protected method.